# Is this the correct way to send multiple arguments to concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

i have to check files in folder structure like this

```
|_HMR
| |__2015
| |__2016
| |__2017
|
|_TMR1
 |__2015
 |__2016
 |__2017
```

i use to call my function like this and it works fine

```
check_continuity('TMR1', 2015)
check_continuity('TMR1', 2016)
check_continuity('TMR1', 2017)
check_continuity('HMR', 2015)
check_continuity('HMR', 2016)
check_continuity('HMR', 2017)
```

but i would like to make this faster by using multiprocessing (concurrent.futures), so is this a right way to send arguments to my function. since first argument has only two variants and second one has three. and i want first argument to run for three different years and then second argument for three different years.

**in short i would like to get the result like my previous way of calling functions individually but faster**

am trying to do like this, but looks like its missing few combinations

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
        print('creating ThreadPoolExecutor')
        start_scrape1 = executor.map(check_continuity, ('HMR', 'TMR1'), (2015, 2016, 2017))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like
You have arguments like `('HMR', 'TMR1')`, `(2015, 2016, 2017)`
So it is taking one from the first one and one from the seconds one making
`('HMR', 2015)`, `('TMR1', 2016)` and since first one is exhausted it is finished.

So what you want to provide is `('HMR','HMR','HMR','TMR1','TMR1','TMR1')` and `(2015, 2016, 2017,2015, 2016, 2017)`

```py
[i for i in p for j in year]
```

is effectively same as

```py
temp = []
for i in p:
    for j in year:
        temp.append(i)
```

which will give `['HMR', 'HMR', 'HMR', 'TMR1', 'TMR1', 'TMR1']`
and `year*len(p)` will provide `(2015, 2016, 2017,2015, 2016, 2017)`

Here the loop works for that

```py
def check_continuity(a,b):
    print(a,b)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=20) as executor:
        print('creating ThreadPoolExecutor')
        p = ('HMR', 'TMR1')
        year = (2015, 2016, 2017)
        start_scrape1 = executor.map(check_continuity, [i for i in p for j in year], year*len(p))
```

output

```
creating ThreadPoolExecutor
HMR 2015
HMR 2016
HMR 2017
TMR1 2015
TMR1TMR1 2017
 2016
```

Comment: sorry am new to coding. just started learning. so this [i for i in p for j in year] is a bit confusing loop. does it do same job as calling individual function ?

Comment: THANKS it works. also thanks for explanation.